# Spring + GWTP: Excel file download from OutputStream not working

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi, gwtp

I have a GWTP application to export some data to an `.xlsx` file using Apache POI. Here is my presenter code.

```
protected void exportTable(String selectedPublisher, String selectedTarget, Drilldown drilldown) {
    this.excelServiceAsync.generateDataEnrichmentExport(selectedPublisher, new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void result) {
            Window.open(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "rpc/excelDownload", "_blank", "");    
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            Window.alert("Error!"); 
        }
    });

}
```

Here is my excel generation code which is asynchronously called by the presenter.

```
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
sheetOne = workbook.createSheet("Export One");

// TODO Typical POI coding stuff

FileOutputStream out = null;

try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(new File("file.xlsx"));
    workbook.write(out);    
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here is my controller which I use to download the excel file.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/excelDownload")
public String downloadExcel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    File file = new File("file.xlsx");

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
            + "file.xlsx");
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));

    FileInputStream is = null;

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

        response.flushBuffer();
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         logger.error(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    } catch (IOException e) {
         logger.error(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "redirect:/error/internal";
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

I'm generating the excel file and putting on the output stream. Then in the controller I get the data from the output stream to download as an `.xlsx` file. This isn't working. The working file is generated and saved on the server. But the file that is downloaded by the browser is a corrupted file. I'm not really sure why. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your `FileOutputStream` `out`. Maybe try using the [`try (resource) {...}` syntax of Java7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)?

Comment: I am closing the `FileOutputStream` in the contoller as `response.getOutputStream().close();` so that's isn't the problem. I have also tried doing `out.close()` in the presenter. Either way, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Edit your post with the updated code, preferably with the try-with-resource syntax as I suggested, so we can all see how you close the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Try set `response.setContentLength((int) file.length());`